# Ajax POST,PUT,DELETE problems with CORS but not every time

Tags: ajax, cors

we are using CORS Filter to send AJAX request between two different domains and we set the configuration properties of this filter by code using OSGI HttpService instead of a web.xml file. The problem is that sometimes (not every time) it doesn't work correctly, it doesn't let us make POST, PUT or DELETE requests. We have add the property `xhrFields:{withCredentials: true}` to these requests but it hasn't change anything.
We have tried to make these requests with Google's Simple Rest Client and we have observed that even when our website is forbidden to perform this request Google's Client always has access.
Does someone know how we can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, try adding the following header: 
**Access-Control-Allow-Methods**: **GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have already tried adding it to the header but it doesn't work. Our server is embeded in OSGI so we register our filter and use the method getCorsFiltersParams() to settle its configuration through a Dictionary. To this Dictionary we added the CORS parameters we need. This is an example of what we are doing: jerseyServletParams.put("cors.supportedMethods","GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"); where jerseyServletParams is our Dictionary. Thank you in advance.